# IOException while reading response

Tags: solr

I get this error message when I try to index files inside one directory. The steps to reproduce this error are following:

```
$ bin/solr stop -all
$ bin/solr start -e cloud 
How many solr nodes ...? 2
Please enter the port for node1 [8983] 8983
Please enter the port for node2 [7574] 7574
Please provide a name for your new collection [gettingstarted] test
How many shard would you like to split test to [2] 2
How many replicas per shard .... [2] 2
Please choose a configuration for test collection .... basic_configs
```

Then, if I go to `localhost:8983/solr/#/` under Core Admin tab I see two shards of a new collection `test`, which we have just created. I then want to index one of my folders and associate this index with `test` collection. I do it like this:

```
bin/post -c test ~/Projects/
```

As a result, I see how files are being indexed, but among all this information I see a lot of such warnings :

```
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response Solr returned an error #400 (Bad request) for url 
http://localhost:8983/solr/test/update
....
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException; 
Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL http://localhost/8983/solr/test/update
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: BTW, as a result of this procedure no files are indexed, judging by `numDocs = 0` under `Core Admin` tab

Comment: Based on this question and several others from you, I would highly suggest you read the manual before posting more questions.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I took the wrong path.